# php как сделать личную страницу для пользователя

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Я еще новичок, только учусь... Объясните пожалуйста, желательно кодом 
При регистрации чтобы автоматически создавалась папка/файл пользователя уже с готовым шаблоном, например как у вконтакте, так чтобы другие пользователи смогли переходить на другие страницы пользователей.

Comment: никто не создает файлы с отдельным пользователем. Информацию хранят с базе данных, а при переходе на `URL` вида `https://domain.com/user/1` из базы вытаскивается значение равное 1 или другому числу, на основе этого заполняется один `HTML` шаблон.

Answer (score 0):

yoursite.com/page/profile.php?userId=1 - твой URL

```
$userId = $_GET['userId'];
```

дальше смотрите, есть ли пользователь с таким вот айди, если да то выводите данные с бд

```
$q = 'SELECT * from users where userId = {$userId}';
$r = mysqli_query($connect, $q);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($r);

echo $row['colName'];
```